# Клик вне элемента

Tags: javascript, jquery

Для чего нужна переменная `firstClick`?

```
$(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('.icon').click(function(){
        $('.header, .content').addClass('active');
        if ($('.sidebar').css('left')!=$('.sidebar').width()) {
            $('.sidebar').addClass('active');
            var firstClick = true;

            // Скрипт который будет закрывать sidebar при клике на любое место
            $(document).bind("click", function() {
                if (!firstClick && $(event.target).closest('.sidebar').length == 0) {
                    // Удаляем класс active
                    $('.sidebar').removeClass('active');
                    // Удаляем класс active
                    $('.header, .content').removeClass('active');
                    $(document).unbind("click");
                }
                firstClick = false;
            });
        }
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Comment: Скорее всего для красоты, поскольку unbind ее перекрывает.

Comment: `$(document).unbind("click");`?! Это ж надо было додуматься до такого...

Comment: А можно обойтись без этого переменного?